Finding maximum Area of a convex quadrilateral inside a unit circle
Here's a question of my own:
• You have a unit circle.
• You want to place two points inside the circle.
• Now from each point you connect them to the nearest point on the circumference.
(Now you have two sides of a quadrilateral)
• Connect the other points such that the quadrilateral is convex
Now you'll have the area of a convex quadrilateral.
Example:

Question:
Where do you want to place the two points to get max area?

What I've tried so far:

I chose two perpendicular diameters, yellow and black. Then I placed two points very close to the center, one of them on the yellow diameter and the other on the black diameter. Now if it was a triangle we'd have 1/2 area units but since we want a quadrilateral it must be just less than 1/2 area units. Is this the correct way to go or is there another method which leads to a better more precise answer? And I'd appreciate if the approach is as simple as possible since my level of math isn't advanced (preferably simple method but not necessarily if it's not possible to find one of course).

Why not have the two points on or near the boundary?

@Paul Because I think we will have a very "narrow" quadrilateral, like my example above. I could be wrong, but I think closer to center is a better option.

Duh, forgot the boundary points were closest to the two points!

Your shape is always included in a isosceles triangle $T$ with opening angle $\alpha\in[0,\pi]$ and leg's length 1. With some trigonometry, you can show that the area of $T$ is $\sin(\alpha)/2$. Therefore, the area of your shape is less $1/2$. Taking $(r,0)$ and $(0,r)$ as your two points, and letting $r$ goes to $0$, you obtain that this bound is optimal.
